# Remove all elements that satisfy a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
        <div class="myClass1">
            <span>tesutokana</span>
        </div>
        <div class="myClass2">
            <span>tesutoroma</span>
        </div>
        <div class="myClass1">
            <span>-</span>
        </div>
        <div class="myClass2">
            <span>-</span>
        </div>
        <div class="myClass1">
            <span>-</span>
        </div>
        <div class="myClass2">
            <span>-</span>
        </div>
```

I want to remove all divs that are just `<span>-</span>` from classes `myClass1` and `myClass2`. Tried with `.each()` but I can't seem to get the hang of it, mostly with what are the arguments of the function I should call. Any help?

Comment: It'd nice to see some javascript code...

Comment: Dumb me, forgot. Wait a sec.

Comment: data attributes are a good approach for such things: `<div class="myClass2" data-empty="true">
            <span>-</span>
        </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by comparing the content of the span in a condition:

```
$('.myClass1, .myClass2').each(function(){
    var mySpan = $(this).find('span');

    if(mySpan.text() == '-'){
        mySpan.closest('div').remove();    
    }
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/8CNkW/2/

## Update:

This one doesn't have the problem with texts containing the `-` string such as `---`, `test-test` etc.

Plush, is 80% faster than the `contains` option named in other answers: http://jsperf.com/just-a-demo

Comment: Just figured out the `parent()` part myself. Thanks.

Comment: I'll be accepting this one since it's more intuitive for me, I prefer to use basic things when it's not much complicated anyway. Thanks to both answer...ers.

Comment: This seems to be a good use case for `.filter`: http://api.jquery.com/filter/. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8CNkW/3/.

Comment: What if span is nested inside. it will remove only the immediate parent. Not the div itself.

Comment: @PSL solved. I just took a look at his HTML markup as if it was not suppose to change.

Comment: What if they are wrapped under another div.. :) it will remove that.. not the intended parent. You would need to use the same selector itself.

Comment: @PSL I based my answer in his question. If there were any special cases he might have named them.

Comment: @Steve In that case you dont need to use closest, parent() was sufficient :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the :contains selector

```
$("div span:contains(-)").remove();
```

Remove the whole div:

```
$("div span:contains(-)").parent().remove();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NMF8M/)

Note that this is a quick and dirty solution as it'll remove all `span`s that contain a *-*

Comment: (+1) Good approach :) But maybe he needs to deal with the classes rather than just with the divs.

Comment: that would be `$(".myClass1, .myClass2").find("span:contains(-)").remove();`

Comment: It ALMOST works, I want to remove whole div, not just the span within a div. Also, wouldn't this remove, for example string "test-test" as well, since it contains "-"? It WON'T make a problem for my specific case, but I'd like to see solution.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović yeah, it would remove the divs with `test-test`. Not as good as I though :)

Comment: This is a dangerous approach. If a span contains a '-' at all it will be removed. `<span>I can back-fire.</span>`

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple solution. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvGxv/1/)

```
var doc = document.body;
doc.innerHTML = doc.innerHTML.replace(/<div(\s)+(.)*class="myClass(1|2)"(.)*>(\s|\n|\t)*<span>-<\/span>(\s|\n|\t)*<\/div>/ig,'');
```

this may be the fastest solution because it's not using a loop or an external library.

or

```
 var j = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass1');
 var t = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass2');
 var x = t.length--;
 while(x--) {
   t[x].innerHTML = t[x].innerHTML.replace(/(<span>-<\/span>)/g,'');
 }
 x = j.length--;

 while(x--) {
   j[x].innerHTML = j[x].innerHTML.replace(/(<span>-<\/span>)/g,'');
 }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvGxv/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use .filter() to do the filtering.

[Just like that:](http://jsfiddle.net/hktTZ/)

```
$('.myClass1,.myClass2').filter(function(i, el){ return el.innerHTML.trim() == '<span>-</span>' }).remove()
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go. I'd probably use `$.trim(el.innerHTML)` though. Not sure on browser support for string.trim().

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.filter()`.

```
$('div').filter(function(){
  var $spans = $(this).find('> span');
  return $spans.length === 1 && $spans.text() === '-';
}).remove();
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VbpzZ/1/

Comment: You don't gain anything from calling `.eq`. Just do `$spans.text()`.

Comment: I always try to be explicit as possible even when I don't need to be. I've adjusted it, though, only because your profile picture is the most glorious unicorn I've ever seen.